# Share a common value among dropdown item and adjust the value on selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a situation where I have been stuck. Actually i have to share the room avalability among condition shown in dropdownlist and after selection in any of dropdownlist the actual room avalability should be maintained.

consider the following scenario in javascript

suppose i have 10 rooms available and there are 3 conditions so we have 3 drop-down for each condition and each drop-down have value from 1-10 initially.

User can select value from any of condition so if user selected 5 from one drop-down then other drop-down should have value 1-5 only. if user select value 2 from second condition then final drop-down should have max selectable value 3. User can play in 10 availability of room but any time max value slected from all condition should not go away than 10.

Can any one give me hint how to do this?

Comment: what have you tried so far? show us some code? Also your question isn't very clear-So the first combo box lists all 10 options, selecting 5 in the first limits the second combo upto that number, and the last combo is limited to the first minus the second?

Comment: Hi deeperm, I wanted to implement that the maximum number of selection in dropdown should not exceed to number of room available. that's why I am restricting user to select upto remaining item from other dropdown list. all dropdown would adjust number of item of other dropdownlist on selection so that at any point user will be able to select maximum 10 from all dropdownlist. Hope it clarify my question

Answer (score 0):

When you select an option from one of the drop-downs, subtract the value from the available total and disable those options from the remaining drop-downs.

```js
$("select").change(function() {
  $("option").prop('disabled', false);
  var select1 = parseInt($("#select1").val(), 10);
  var select2 = parseInt($("#select2").val(), 10);
  if (!isNaN(select1)) {
    var select2_max = 10 - select1;
    $("#select2 option").slice(select2_max + 1).prop('disabled', true);
    $("#select3 option").slice(select2_max + 1).prop('disabled', true);
    if (!isNaN(select2)) {
      var select3_max = select2_max - select2;
      $("#select3 option").slice(select3_max + 1).prop('disabled', true);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select1">
  <option value="">Select</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="4">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
</select>
<select id="select2">
  <option value="">Select</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="4">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
</select>
<select id="select3">
  <option value="">Select</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="4">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks Barmar, your solution is very much close to my problem just one thing which I could not mentioned in my question really sorry for that is all these three dropdown should work in circular way so change in any dropdown would enable/disable the option of other dropdown. so that maximum posibility of selection in all dropdown should be number of available rooms. But I would say you have given me a thinking point. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: If you can modify to work in circular way in all dropdown that will help me

Comment: Actually I have less experience in jquery stuff which causes I am facing issues. Any way thanks for help I will try by self.